# C# write to ext2 linux partition from Windows

Tags: c#, windows, linux, disk-partitioning, ext2

I'm quite new to C# and I need to write a file (grub) on an EXt2 linux partition from windows 7.

What is the good way to do such thing?  Do I need to mount the partition with external program?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to mount it with an external program such as: http://www.fs-driver.org/

Answer (score 1):

Mount the drive using a a driver like [FS-driver](http://www.fs-driver.org/) and then write to it using standard C# file writing techniques.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ext2Fsd to mount the partition in windows, and then write to as you would any other partition.

[EXT2FSD Home Page](http://www.ext2fsd.com/)

Answer (score 0):

If you use Total Commander under Windows, one of the available plugins is for accessing ext2/3/4.  It's probably already been mentioned here but it makes accessing Linux from Windows almost transparent.  I don't have it installed right now or I'd look at the name.

Answer (score 0):

SharpExt4 may help you with Linux file system read and write.

A .Net library to provide full access (read/write) to Linux ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystem

Here is the GitHub link
https://github.com/nickdu088/SharpExt4

```
//Open EXT4 SD Card
//Here is SD Card physical disk number. you can get from Windows disk manager
ExtDisk SharpExt4.ExtDisk.Open(int DiskNumber);
//In your case FAT32 is 1st one, ext4 is 2nd one
//Open EXT4 partition
var fs = ExtFileSystem.Open(disk.Parititions[1]); 

//Create /home/pi/file.conf file for write
var file = fs.OpenFile("/home/pi/file.conf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
var hello = "Hello World";
var buf = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(hello);
//Write to file
file.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
file.Close();
```

[How to use SharpExt4 to access Raspberry Pi SD Card Linux partition](https://www.nickdu.com/?p=919)